# OpenCVを使って、傾いてしまった写真を正確な位置に戻したい

Tags: objective-c, c++, opencv

iPhoneのカメラを使って写真を撮った時に、斜めに傾いてしまった写真を正確な位置に戻したいです。

iPhoneの連写アプリなどをつかって何枚か写真を撮った時、写真1のようにまっすぐ撮れた写真と写真2のように少し傾いてしまった写真があったとします。傾いてしまった写真2をまっすぐにするために、写真1を基準にし何かしらのアルゴリズム(★1)を使って、写真2を補正したいと考えています。OpenCVにおいて、この問題を解決できるアルゴリズムは存在するでしょうか？

[image: 写真1と写真2]
[image: 写真2の補正]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

こちらの記事が参考になるのではないでしょうか。
[Opencvを使ってパノラマ写真を作る](http://goya813.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/11/30/180002)

この記事のソースコードでは、以下の様な変換を行っています。

1. 2枚の写真のSIFT特徴量を抽出し、
2. 特徴量のマッチングを行い
3. 画像間のホモグラフィ行列を求め
4. 写真2を写真1平面に透視変換した画像(写真3とする)を作成
5. 写真3に写真1を貼り付ける

上記のステップうち、5.のステップを端折れば良いかと。

記事に掲載されているソースコードの最後の部分を以下のように改変します。

```
Mat homo = cv::findHomography(points1, points2, CV_RANSAC);
cv::warpPerspective(src[0], result, homo, Size(src[0].cols, src[0].rows));

imshow("result img", result);
waitKey(0);
```

この`result`が求めるべき写真2(完成)になると思われます。

Comment: 的確なご回答ありがとうございます！
変換の流れがよく理解できました。